# Convert Excel to PDF (read only / non editable version) using SaveToStream

Tags: c#

I am working with Spire XLS library to convert excel to pdf.
Is there some way to add read-only / not editable attribute into a pdf file?

My coding is as the below. Thanks.

```
Workbook wb = new Workbook();
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];
//set cell value
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   wb.SaveToStream(memoryStream, Spire.Xls.FileFormat.PDF);
   byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
   memoryStream.Close();
   using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
   {
       // SMTP Setting
       mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "Attachment.pdf", "Application/pdf"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to post the question to its technical support forum to get better help：

http://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/spire-xls-f4.html